# PHP Error: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Tags: php

Добрый день! Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой:

```
  Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 58
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как ее решить.

Заранее, спасибо.

```
<?php

interface FileInterface {

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param string $filePath
 */
public function __construct($filePath);


/**
 * Returns the file name
 *
 * @return string the relative path
 */
public function getFileName();


/**
 * Check if file located in specific directory
 *
 * @param DirectoryInfo $directory
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isInDirectory(DirectoryInfo $directory);

}


/**
 * Реалізувати клас
 */
 class DirectoryInfo {
  # ваш код тут
 public function __construct($directory){
    $this->directory = $directory;
 } 
 }

 /**
  * Реалізувати інтерфейс
  */
 class File implements FileInterface {
 # ваш код тут
 public function __construct($filePath){
    $this->filePath = $filePath;
  }

public function getFileName(){
    $file = basename($this->filePath);
    echo $file;
}

public function isInDirectory(DirectoryInfo $directory){

    $filePathArray = explode("/", $this->filePath);
    $directoryArray = explode("/", $directory);
    $i = 0;

    while ($i < count($directoryArray)){
        if ($filePathArray[$i] != $directoryArray[$i]){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
            $i++;
    }
}
}


# цей код має працювати
$file = new File(__FILE__);
$file->isInDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(__DIR__)); // return true


$file = new File('/tmp/data/test.txt');
$file->isInDirectory(new DirectoryInfo('/tmp/data/')); // return true
$file->isInDirectory(new DirectoryInfo('/tmp')); // return true
$file->isInDirectory(new DirectoryInfo('/tmp/other')); // return false
$file->isInDirectory(new DirectoryInfo('/tmp/data/test')); // return false

$file->getFileName(); //return test.txt

?>
```

Comment: видимо здесь у вас ошибка `$directoryArray = explode("/", $directory);` а дальше все написано - $directory не строка, а объект.  Про что, собственно,  написано в ошибке

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаёте в метод `isInDirectory` объект, даже проверяете его тип, а следом используете этот объект в `$directoryArray = explode("/", $directory);` как источник, который должен быть строкой.